# How to replace multiple instances of substring within a string

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, stringbuilder

I need to replace some of the contents of a large string with different content in the same spot.

Lets say I have a string:

```
String str = "package blah.foo.bar;\n"
           + "import org.blah.blah;\n"
           + "import sel.this.that;\n"
           + "import sel.boo.foo;\n"
           + "...more text";
```

I want to insert the word `gen` into statements which start with `import sel.` So that the end result looks like: `import sel.gen.this.that;`

I have had success with the following method but only when I KNOW where that substring will be within the string. My issue is that I'm not sure how to make the following code dynamic:

```
private String modifyString(String str){
    String hold = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(";"));
    hold = new StringBuilder(hold).insert(13, "gen.").toString();
    str = str.replace("(?m)^package.*", hold);
    return str;

}
```

The above code correctly replaces the strings `package blah.foo.bar;` with `package blah.gen.foo.bar;`

But again this only works with replacing the beginning portion of the string. I'm looking to be able to hold all instances of a substring and then insert a substring within those substrings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple line like:

```
str = str.replaceAll("import sel\\.", "import sel.gen.");
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB1fJ4/1)**

**[IdeOne example](https://ideone.com/iJjcZ8)**

Comment: Thank you. I have been staring at this for too long!

Comment: @panthor314 glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

`replace`  takes a literal string expression as an argument, not a regex.

This should work and is simpler than using a regex:

```
String result = str.replace("import sel.", "import sel.gen.");
```